# how to switch "process" on with Python IDLE

Tags: python, subprocess, python-idle

I am using Python IDLE 2.7.8. The IDLE shows "No Subprocess" as follow:

Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

==== No Subprocess ====

I could import subprocess module successfully. But how can I switch to "==== Subprocess ====" mode? I spend hours but find no way to do that. who could help me please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If one starts IDLE with `-n`, which means "no subprocess, run user code in the IDLE process", then it prints "No Subprocess" after the rest of the startup header as a reminder that one in not running in normal mode.

The way to start in normal 'run user code in a subprocess' mode is to not pass the '-n' flag.  Look at how your are starting IDLE.  It must involve a startup line with '-n' somewhere.